# IWindsorContainer as a parameter to a class

Tags: .net, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I have a class that I want to have access to my IOC container (Windsor), however I don't want to keep a static IWindsorContainer property hanging around - I would prefer to have the container inject itself into any classes that require an IWindsorContainer as a constructor dependency.

I've pulled this off with Unity, but when I try the same thing with the Windsor container it tells me that IWindsorContainer is not registered with the container.

I don't think I can just register IWindsorContainer => WindsorContainer, because that will cause the container to create a new (or different) instance of itself to pass to my class, and that instance won't have all my other types registered with it. I also don't see a way to construct the container, register all the types in it, and then register that instance of itself against IWindsorContainer - all of the registration methods only take types for service and implementation - never an actual concrete instance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally you don't want to inject the container into your application components.

See these questions (this question is almost a duplicate of them):

- [Usage of IoC Containers; specifically Windsor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367178/usage-of-ioc-containers-specifically-windsor)
- [NInject: Where do you keep your reference to the Kernel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590900/ninject-where-do-you-keep-your-reference-to-the-kernel)
- [IoC, Where do you put the container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109668/ioc-where-do-you-put-the-container)

**BTW**: you get `IKernel` injection for free, and you **can** register `IWindsorContainer`:

```
container.Register(Component.For<IWindsorContainer>().Instance(container));
```

Comment: IKernal worked for me. Didn't need the whole WindsorContainer for my class.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, like mausch said, think twice before you pass your container to your component. Do you **really** need it to have access to the container?

To pull dependencies from the container use [typed factories](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Typed-Factory-Facility.ashx).

Answer (score 0):

I was tempted to do this recently.  I wanted to be able to create multiple instances of a service during the lifetime of an object.  Registering a factory would be better in that the need for the dependency is clearer.  But creating a factory per service seemed like a pain.

I ended up using something like the code in this article: http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2010/01/10-advanced-windsor-tricks-1a-delegate.html.  Suppose you have a class that needs to create instances of IService.  The article describes a technique allowing your class to have a dependency on Func, and you'll automatically get a factory specific to that class.